# Window.Parent.Postmessage with Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I'm working with an IFrame on my page and making a Communication with Cross Domain IFrame - A Cross Browser Solution using .postmessage in java script

in my IFRAME target page I have something like this:

```
window.parent.postMessage("Assign to value1", "www.parentpage.com");
window.parent.postMessage("Assign to value2", "www.parentpage.com");
```

then in my parent page :

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
var value1 = e.data;
var value2 = e.data;

}, false);
```

I tested it and Its working with single var using value1 only.

Now I want to parametarized my .postmessage if its possible so that I can get the message dynamically.
I'm expecting a result of :

```
value1=Assign to value1
value2=Assign to value2
```

Any suggestion on how can I achieve that result?

Answer (score 30):

**Cross domain** script:

```
window.parent.postMessage(
    {
        event_id: 'my_cors_message',
        data: {
            v1: 'value1', 
            v2: 'value2'
        }
    }, 
    "*" //or "www.parentpage.com"
);
```

**Client / parent** script:

```
window.addEventListener('cors_event', function(event) {
    if(event.data.event_id === 'my_cors_message'){
        console.log(event.data.data);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
{v1: 'value1', v2: 'value2'}
```

Comment: note: You can't provide multiple [targetOrigins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35939961/234110). It has to be * if you want multiple targetOrigins

Comment: **note2**: if `window.addEventListener('cors_event',..` did not work, replace `cors_event` with `message`.

Comment: after replacing it's not working any new suggestions thanks @AnandRockzz

Answer (score 7):

Simply pass an object as the `data`:

```
window.parent.postMessage({v1: 'Assign to value1', v2: 'Assign to value2'}, "www.parentpage.com");
```

And then, in the receiver function body:

```
var value1 = e.data.v1
var value2 = e.data.v2
```